# Mathematica DSolve diff. equation over a particular domain

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations, dsolve

I am looking for a way to solve the following differential equation:

```
DSolve[(1 - b*Abs[z])*f[z]/a == f''[z], f[z], z]
```

Therefore I tried to DSolve it distinguishing z>0 from z<0 such as:

```
DSolve[(1 - b*z)*f[z]/a == f''[z], f[z], z>0]
```

But I still does not work.
Maybe adding a domain explicitly would help but I can't find a way to do so.

Does anyone has any idea how do do such things?

Thank you for your help and time

Comment: It is quite doubtful that a symbolic solution exists. Would a numerical solution be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your assumptions on to the solver with `Refine`:

```
Refine[DSolve[(1 - b*Abs[z])*f[z]/a == f''[z], f[z], z], z > 0]
```

gives

```
{{f[z] -> AiryAi[(1/a - (b z)/a)/(-(b/a))^(2/3)] C[1] + AiryBi[(1/a - (b z)/a)/(-(b/a))^(2/3)] C[2]}}
```

Comment: Thank you! although I'm not sure how I should understand the term (-(b/a))^(2/3). I still have it even when I add the assumption {z > 0, a > 0, b > 0}

Comment: I also found out that it is possible to use the `Assuming` option such as :
`Assuming[z > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0, 
 DSolve[(1 - b*z)*f[z]/a == f''[z], f[z], z]]`